# Obtener fecha de un valor máximo agrupando por id - Python

Tags: python, pandas

tengo este dataframe en Python:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito agrupar por idCDU y sacar la fechaValor del valor máximo para cada idCDU.

Este ha sido mi intento de varios:

`df_max_fecha = df_max_fecha.groupby(['idCDU', 'fechaValor'])['valor'].max().reset_index()`

Cualquier idea es bienvenida.

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Puedes proporcionar un enlace de donde descargar datos de ejemplo para hacer pruebas? O si no al menos una muestra de tu dataframe pero como texto y no como imagen?

Comment: Hola @abufalia! Claro, el link es el siguiente: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1f6LDZcFen4nA4lQQ15g9D0SVQweKzTOa?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy bastante seguro de que tiene que haber un método menos retorcido, pero esto es lo único que se me ha ocurrido:

- Haces un `groupby()` por la columna "idCDU"
- Haces un `.apply(funcion)` sobre el resultado. La función en cuestión recibirá como parámetro cada uno de los sub-dataframes en que haya sido agrupado el dataframe principal, así que dentro de esa función puedes indexar por la columna "fechaValue" y usar `.valor.idxmax()` para retornar el índice (que será entonces la fecha) de la fila que tiene el valor máximo.

Aunque la idea es retorcida, la implementación son un par de líneas:

```
# Leer dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv", sep=";", index_col=0)

# Implementación de la idea
def getmax(subdf):
  return subdf.set_index("fechaValor").valor.idxmax()
  
df_max_fecha = df.groupby("idCDU").apply(getmax)
```

El resultado en `df_max_fecha` saldría:

```markdown
ATD-987    12/12/2019 15:04
IEC-229    16/12/2019 17:09
```

Comment: Hola! Me ha funcionado, muchas gracias! Quería preguntarte a ver si sabes como pasarlo a formato dataframe, porque el resultado me sale como "registros sueltos": idCDU
ATD-987   2019-12-12 15:04:15
IEC-229   2019-12-16 17:09:36
dtype: datetime64[ns]

Comment: Lo que te sale es un "pandas series" (una columna). Fácilmente puedes convertirlo en dataframe con `pd.DataFrame(resultado)`

Comment: muchas gracias @abulafia